# Scala trait and class inheritence tree

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I have trouble understanding the output of my program. I am not sure, why I get the output that I do. Following are the involved classes/traits

```
class SuperClass {

  def superMethodFromClass() = {println("from super class")};

}

trait SuperTrait extends SuperClass{

  def superMethod():Unit={}
  override def superMethodFromClass() = {println("from super trait")};

}

class TestClass extends SuperClass with SuperTrait{

  def callSMFC() = superMethodFromClass()

}
```

When I use the following code in the main method:-

```
val testClass = new TestClass
    testClass.callSMFC
```

it prints "from super trait"

Can some one please explain why this happens ???

Thanks,

Amar

Comment: I suppose it's because inheritance works from right to left so the `SuperTrait` method is overriding the `SuperClass` one in your `TestClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scala compiler uses linearization to combine (multiple traits) into classes.

You could see your example of several things being stacked on top of each other. Your `TestClass` inherits from `SuperClass` and then `SuperTrait` is stacked on top.

When calling `superMethodFromClass()`, the first place to look for an implementation is the `TestClass` itself, however since `TestClass` did not override the method, the compiler will look first in `SuperTrait`, hence you see that `"from super trait"` is printed.

For more details check the link below about the stackable trait pattern
https://code.sahebmotiani.com/patterns-in-scala-101-5d0fa70aaf3f